# Google Doubleclick async ad not loading in cross domain iframe

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, iframe, double-click

The ad loads fine when going to the iframe url directly but when the page is brought in via iframe the ad doesn't load.  I tried creating a /doubleclick/DARTIframe.html file at the root of the iframe domain based on the instructions below but it still doesn't work.

https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/156583

Is there any other way to keep the ads from getting blocked when loading in an iframe?

Comment: Is it possible that this is intentional on Google's part?

Comment: I think its just async javascript files are getting blocked due to being on different domains